# Django Rest Framework Allow a request to set a foreign key Field in CreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

A thread belongs to a board. So I would like the ThreadList view to accept a POST request with the  foreign key `board`. What I have attempted results in an error. `AssertionError: Relational field must provide a queryset argument, override get_queryset, or set read_only=True`

`serializers.py`

```
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    post = PostSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    # board = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='board.id')
    board = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='board.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'post', 'board']
```

`views.py`

```
class ThreadList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(thread_admin=self.request.user)

    queryset = Thread.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ThreadSerializer
```

`models.py`

```
class Board(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board_admin = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='board_admin')
    board_moderator = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='board_moderator')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']


class Thread(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thread_admin = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='thread')
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="thread")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField` has a required argument `queryset` that needs to include to tell what id of which `queryset` needs to be validated against.

In your case, it should be

```py
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    board = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Board.objects.all())
    ...
```

## Notes

Notice that you don't need to specify `source='board.id'` since `django-rest-framework` already handles that for you.

## Extra

If there's no extra parameters that will be pass into `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField` to change the default behavior, you can just include `board` in `class Meta`'s `fields` and no need to use `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField` manually.

```py
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = PostSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'post', 'board']
```